# Trying to use a jQuery file in Wordpress, which requires noConflict, but now my Object [object Object] has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, conflict

I'm trying to include stickem in a Wordpress theme I'm building. It is right here on GitHub, with a demo and some documentation: https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem

The .js file uses $, which is known to conflict in Wordpress, so I replaced every instance of `$` with `jQuery`, and called `jQuery.noConflict();` at the top.

Before I called noConflict, my error console told me "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function." Now that message has been replaced by "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stickem'" and stickem still isn't working.

You can see my wordpress instance here:
http://lehuagray.com/trendsnap/

Here is my altered code:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('.container').stickem({
    item: '.stickem',
    container: '.stickem-container',
    stickClass: 'stickit',
    endStickClass: 'stickit-end',
    offset: 0,
    onStick: null,
    onUnstick: null
});


;(function(jQuery, window, document, undefined) {

var Stickem = function(elem, options) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.jQueryelem = jQuery(elem);
    this.options = options;
    this.metadata = this.jQueryelem.data("stickem-options");
    this.jQuerywin = jQuery(window);
};

Stickem.prototype = {
    defaults: {
        item: '.stickem',
        container: '.stickem-container',
        stickClass: 'stickit',
        endStickClass: 'stickit-end',
        offset: 0,
        start: 0,
        onStick: null,
        onUnstick: null
    },

    init: function() {
        var _self = this;

        //Merge options
        _self.config = jQuery.extend({}, _self.defaults, _self.options, _self.metadata);

        _self.setWindowHeight();
        _self.getItems();
        _self.bindEvents();

        return _self;
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        var _self = this;

        _self.jQuerywin.on('scroll.stickem', jQuery.proxy(_self.handleScroll, _self));
        _self.jQuerywin.on('resize.stickem', jQuery.proxy(_self.handleResize, _self));
    },

    destroy: function() {
        var _self = this;

        _self.jQuerywin.off('scroll.stickem');
        _self.jQuerywin.off('resize.stickem');
    },

    getItem: function(index, element) {
        var _self = this;
        var jQuerythis = jQuery(element);
        var item = {
            jQueryelem: jQuerythis,
            elemHeight: jQuerythis.height(),
            jQuerycontainer: jQuerythis.parents(_self.config.container),
            isStuck: false
        };

        //If the element is smaller than the window
        if(_self.windowHeight > item.elemHeight) {
            item.containerHeight = item.jQuerycontainer.outerHeight();
            item.containerInner = {
                border: {
                    bottom: parseInt(item.jQuerycontainer.css('border-bottom'), 10) || 0,
                    top: parseInt(item.jQuerycontainer.css('border-top'), 10) || 0
                },
                padding: {
                    bottom: parseInt(item.jQuerycontainer.css('padding-bottom'), 10) || 0,
                    top: parseInt(item.jQuerycontainer.css('padding-top'), 10) || 0
                }
            };

            item.containerInnerHeight = item.jQuerycontainer.height();
            item.containerStart = item.jQuerycontainer.offset().top - _self.config.offset + _self.config.start + item.containerInner.padding.top + item.containerInner.border.top;
            item.scrollFinish = item.containerStart - _self.config.start + (item.containerInnerHeight - item.elemHeight);

            //If the element is smaller than the container
            if(item.containerInnerHeight > item.elemHeight) {
                _self.items.push(item);
            }
        } else {
            item.jQueryelem.removeClass(_self.config.stickClass + ' ' + _self.config.endStickClass);
        }
    },

    getItems: function() {
        var _self = this;

        _self.items = [];

        _self.jQueryelem.find(_self.config.item).each(jQuery.proxy(_self.getItem, _self));
    },

    handleResize: function() {
        var _self = this;

        _self.getItems();
        _self.setWindowHeight();
    },

    handleScroll: function() {
        var _self = this;

        if(_self.items.length > 0) {
            var pos = _self.jQuerywin.scrollTop();

            for(var i = 0, len = _self.items.length; i < len; i++) {
                var item = _self.items[i];

                //If it's stuck, and we need to unstick it
                if(item.isStuck && (pos < item.containerStart || pos > item.scrollFinish)) {
                    item.jQueryelem.removeClass(_self.config.stickClass);

                    //only at the bottom
                    if(pos > item.scrollFinish) {
                        item.jQueryelem.addClass(_self.config.endStickClass);
                    }

                    item.isStuck = false;

                    //if supplied fire the onUnstick callback
                    if(_self.config.onUnstick) {
                        _self.config.onUnstick(item);
                    }

                //If we need to stick it
                } else if(item.isStuck === false && pos > item.containerStart && pos < item.scrollFinish) {
                        item.jQueryelem.removeClass(_self.config.endStickClass).addClass(_self.config.stickClass);
                        item.isStuck = true;

                        //if supplied fire the onStick callback
                        if(_self.config.onStick) {
                            _self.config.onStick(item);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    setWindowHeight: function() {
        var _self = this;

        _self.windowHeight = _self.jQuerywin.height() - _self.config.offset;
    }
};

Stickem.defaults = Stickem.prototype.defaults;

jQuery.fn.stickem = function(options) {
    //Create a destroy method so that you can kill it and call it again.
    this.destroy = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            new Stickem(this, options).destroy();
        });
    };

    return this.each(function() {
        new Stickem(this, options).init();
    });
};

})(jQuery, window , document);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't use a function before it has been defined. Right now, your call to `stickem` is before the definition of `stickem`. You need to put your code inside a `jQuery(function() { });` block to defer execution until the DOM is ready (which, as a side effect, also allows the `stickem` function to be defined before you attempt to use it.)

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.container').stickem({
    item: '.stickem',
    container: '.stickem-container',
    stickClass: 'stickit',
    endStickClass: 'stickit-end',
    offset: 0,
    onStick: null,
    onUnstick: null
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your functions and jQuery code in this:

```
;(function ($) {

    //Code in here

})(jQuery);
```

This assigns the `$` to jQuery only. Doing this prevents conflicts with other libraries/code that also use the `$`. Also leading this code with a `;` protects your function from unclosed scripts. I wouldn't rely on the `noConflict()` method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    //You can do it like this too
    //Make sure to replace all your 'jQuery' referecens to '$'
    //jQuery.extend({}, _self.defaults, _self.options, _self.metadata)
    $.extend({}, _self.defaults, _self.options, _self.metadata)
})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the no conflict mode only when you want to release $ for other libraries.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Release $ for other js libraries.
```

Try to wrap your jQuery code like so:

```
(function($) {
  // Inside this function $ is jQuery    

  $(document).ready({
    // jQuery code goes here.
  })
})(jQuery);
```